# Cordova google-analytics-plugin causing phonegap iOS build to fail

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I installed the cordova google-analytics plugin ([1](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin)) for my phonegap app and it works fine with android but it causes my iOS build to fail (if I remove the plugin then I can run the iOS build successfully again. When I run `phonegap build ios` I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [115/15414]
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore tableExists:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore bindRecord:toUpsertStatement:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore selectStmtWithTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore closeDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl closeDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore rowCountForTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore hasValidPropertyColumns] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
      -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore propertyRecordForTrackingId:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_errcode", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl prepareSql:description:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
"_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [61/15414]
      -[GAISqlStore errorMessage] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntriesOlderThan:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl tablePresent:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore removeStatementForQuery:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore finalizeAndClearStatements] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore prepareSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore executeSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl openDatabaseAndInitStatements] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore prepareSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl prepareSql:description:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore rowCountForTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore tableExists:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore dropTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentS
toreImpl numStoredEntries] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[GAISqlStore rowCountForTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore openAndValidateDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore tableExists:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore dropTableWithName:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[GAISqlStore executeSql:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAISqlStore.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl clearKeysWithPrefixSingleThreaded:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl loadSerialized] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:

        Ld build/emulator/Treys.app/Treys normal i386
(1 failure)

Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,Treys.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,Treys,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_B
UILD_DIR=/Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

I checked the XCode project and `libsqlite3.dylib` is in the list of Frameworks and I explicitly added `-lsqlite3` to the list of linking flags in the build settings. When I then try to build it in XCode I get a long list of almost identical errors. Below is a truncated piece of the output:

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGTrackingTag.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGPValueHash.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
    /Users/Rylan/cisc/intoli/treys/phonegap/platforms/ios/Treys/Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGPValueHash.o)
ld: 230 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Cordova: 5.4.0

Phonegap: 5.3.6

XCode: 6.2

OSX: 10.9.5

Comment: seems it is adding the framework twice to your xcode proj.

Comment: You can try with http://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google

Comment: I tried to install the appfeel plugin but npf failed to install it. Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-analytics':Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-google-play-services

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the plugin, building ios and then readding the plugin. Rebuilding ios after that might do the trick.

If that fails, try removing the plugin and the platform and add again to rebuild.

The second option worked for me.